# Create a timestamp in a specific cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to create a timestamp in a Google Sheet when a specific cell is edited. I need the timestamp to be added to cell B2 when cell A3 is edited. I also need the timestamp to be written as uppercase (in the format of 'FEBRUARY 20'). I have amended the date format in Google Sheets so it is displayed as month then year, but it also needs capitalising (Google Sheets is automatically formatting as 'February 20'). The code I have is

```
function onEdit(e) {

addTimestamp(e);

}


function addTimestamp(e){
//variables
var startRow = 3;
var targetColumn = 1;
var ws = "template";

//get modified row and column
var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();

if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){

var currentDate = new Date();

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,2).setValue(currentDate);
if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3),getValue() == ""){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(currentDate);
} //END IF check if date created exists
} //END IF check column, row, worksheet
} //END function addTimestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='************Your sheet name here*********')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==3) {
    var M=['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER'];
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    var ts= M[new Date().getMonth()] + " " + new Date().getDate();
    //e.source.toast(ts);
    sh.getRange(2,2).setValue(ts);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper! Thanks for this. I'm going to check this over and see if I can get it working. I'll let you know how I go.